# Map nested angular $resource to existing object in MEAN-setup

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose, mean-stack, ngresource

I have a question on how best to structure the following idea:

As a (simplified) model I have a `Box`-object which contains some properties, and has a set of `Items`.
Such an `item` has some general properties (name is the same for all items, value is not), and some specific propererties that are only of use for that particular type of `Item`. I also have a function makeLabel() on the items which should return a string representation created from the properties, this is also dependent on the type of `Item`.

Here's a quick example of this.

Box-object

```
function Box(){
    this.height;
    this.width;
    this.depth;
    ...
    this.items = [];
}
```

ToyItem-object:

```
function ToyItem(){
    this.name;        //general
    this.description; //general

    this.minimumAge;

    this.getLabel = function(){
        return "This toy (" + this.name + ") is for children age " + this.minimumAge + " and up";
    }
}
```

BookItem-object:

```
function BookItem(){
    this.name;        //general
    this.description; //general

    this.owner;

    this.getLabel = function(){
        return "This book (" + this.name + ") is owned by " + this.owner;
    }

}
```

I am / will be using AngularJS / $resource on the frontend, and Express/mongoose/mongodb on the backend. So the typical MEAN stack.
The number of items will be variable. I want to be able to 'make up' `item`-objects as I go, without having to alter the backend.

Right now I only have an api-endpoint for `Box` and the items of the box are just stored as an "array of objects".
When I use AngularJS $resource to query the `Box`-endpoint I get the Box-$resource with an array of 'generic objects' back. Is there a way casting them to ToyItem, BookItem,... in order to use my specific defined functions?

It would also be nice to be able to call $save and $delete directly on the item, instead of always updating the box opject.

I have control over the whole stack, so I can make changes to every part. I just want some guidance as to what is the best approach for this type of problem.

Comment: I've been asking myself similar questions. Did you arrive at a solution?